# Условие в условии

Tags: python, условия

Может ли быть условие в условии?

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: что мешает взять и проверить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

да, это будет вложенный условный оператор.
для Python есть например такое:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x > 0:
    if y > 0:
        print('Первая четверть')
    else:
        print('Четвертая четверть')
else:
    if y > 0:
        print('Вторая четверть')
    else:
        print('Третья четверть')
```

почитать можете здесь, пример отсюда же взят:
https://stepik.org/lesson/265082/step/1